# Does jQuery1.5 have an Auto complete widget in their api?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, widget

Does Jquery1.5 has Auto Complete widget included in their api. We are using jQuery1.5 and i have a requirement that to have auto complete implemented for Search Box. By goggling i see that jquery1.8 has it. I don't think we will get an approval for jquery1.8. If its not there how should i create my own widget in Jquery?

Comment: jQuery has no widgets and it's up to version 1.6 ... maybe you're thinking about jQuery **UI**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery **UI** 1.8 has the autocomplete widget. jQuery core (as in, not jQuery UI or jQuery mobile) does not have any widgets.

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com) has an auto complete widget.  There is no autocomplete widget in jQuery itself.

Comment: What is the difference between jQuery UI and Jquery?

Comment: jQuery UI offers widgets such as datepicker, colorpickers, sliders, animation effects and pretty a lot of stuff. http://jqueryui.com/